# Convert html to pdf in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I am using [dompdf library](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf) to convert html content to pdf.I am facing some problems.

1) I am able to generate pdf but On My HTML content there are some images but when I am generating pdf images are not coming in PDF.

2) Also PDF is not showing complete data means data is coming surely but not visible of complete width.

Please help!!!

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806462/codeignitor-how-to-create-pdf/19806926#19806926

Comment: keep in mind dompdf has it's share of css to pdf issues. Don't uses nested tables, and avoid floats

Comment: @SpYk3HH your information may be out of date. Nested tables are fine. Floats are a work in progress, but some support is present. The biggest issue right now is the inability of dompdf to split a table cell across pages which can lead to, at the least, broken rendering and, at the worst, resource exhaustion. That issue may be why you have a bad view of nested tables.

Comment: @BrianS LoL, your information is out of date. I was referring to my recent download and use of latest lib just last week!

Comment: @SpYk3HH what release did you download? Though the last "stable" release was 0.5.1 we highly recommend 0.6.0, even though it's currently in beta. As I said dompdf does support [nested tables](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=2984a3df16df6eb2a87422e16031b49d) and [floats](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=87bd55b46cb7c1a18cbc0109623c793a).

Comment: @SpYk3HH also, the reason I commented is that you were being overly broad in your complaint. No doubt there are weaknesses in the library and I won't deny that. But it's important that if you're going to respond to a question you should strive for accuracy and completeness as much as possible.

Comment: @SpYk3HH since we're getting waaaaay off topic feel free to post something here or to the [support group](http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf) if you are so inclined. We're always happy to try and figure out where things are breaking, to create issues to cover new problems, and to suggest work-arounds where possible. I think some of your issues should be easily addressed (like the table position).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41978/discussion-between-brians-and-spyk3hh)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample of making my html to pdf...I wish i give you some idea

LIBRARIES:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dompdf_gen {

    public function __construct() {

        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

        $pdf = new DOMPDF();

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->dompdf = $pdf;

    }

}
```

Controller:

```
function pdf($id){

            $data['contract_items_all']     = $this->contract_items->get_serial_infos($this->uri->segment(4));
            $data['child_info']             = $this->contract_items->get_children_info($cid);

            $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
            $html = $this->load->view('contracts/equipment_pdf', $data, true);//this equipment_pdf contain the html that you will convert to pdf
            $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
            $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

            // Convert to PDF
            $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
            $this->dompdf->render();
            $this->dompdf->stream("Contract.pdf",array("Attachment"=>0)); // VIEW IN OTHER TAB
            //$this->dompdf->stream("Contract.pdf"); // SAVE FILE TO DISK
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you loading libraries twice?

```
// ...

$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
$html = $this->load->view('contracts/equipment_pdf', $data, true);//this equipment_pdf contain the html that you will convert to pdf
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

// ...
```