# how to print a receipt to a particular printer

Tags: codeigniter, google-chrome, printing, libraries

I have a point of sale application which is developed using a code igniter frame work,which works only in chrome browser, I have two buttons in my application

1. send to kitchen
2. pay BILL

when I click sent to kitchen button a print should be come in printer which is kept in kitchen,
when I click pay BILL a bill should be come from the printer which is kept in cashier table.

I will be OK to do this with any libraries or google chrome API's

Comment: you can export your HTML to pdf then print it  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806462/codeigniter-how-to-create-pdf

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by sending a text file (most POS printer support text file printing) to the attached network printers (IP address and port).

you can use exec() function of PHP for that.

go through the thread below for the clue

[printing over network from PHP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694144/printing-over-network-from-php-app)